# Why is my reputation for this quarter greater than my total reputation?

Tags: support, reputation, rankings, total-reputation

I was checking my reputation on Stack Overflow when something surprised me.

> [image: Reputation]

I don't understand why my quarter reputation is above my total reputation.
I would like to know if this is a bug, or if there is something I've just misunderstood on this page.